# Product page zoom level

Tags: product, zoom, product-page

I'm dealing with the Magento out of the box zoom function and I can't find a way to modify the level of zoom of it. The requirement is simple, the zoom level is to big. 
Changing the image with one of better quality to reduce the size of the zoomed square is not an option for now.

Is there any chance to do this? I don't need to change the proportion of the images or anything like the things I read in other questions.
I only need to pass a value to the zoom function and make the image in the zoom square smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding Magento version 1.8 and less do not zoom the image as such but simply shows the image in full. See `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

For version 1.9 with the rwd design installed I think it simply resizes the image to width 1200px. See `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):
        $_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                          ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())
                          ->keepFrame(false)
                          ->constrainOnly(true)
                          ->resize(1200);
?>
    <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>"
         class="gallery-image"
         src="<?php echo $_imageUrl; ?>"
         data-zoom-image="<?php echo  $_imageUrl; ?>" />
<?php
    $i++;
    endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change zoom with [Magento Elevate Zoom extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-page-elevate-zoom.html)